# Quick logarithm calculation

Tags: logarithms, binary

In coming up with an algorithm for finding $\log (10)$ base $2$, these are my thoughts. I wanted to know if this makes sense and how could I truly make it more efficient. The requirements are strictly not using any kind of tables.

Suppose I want to find $\log (11)$ base $2$.

- Step1: Calculate the next highest power of $2$ from $11$ - answer $16$ and next lowest power of $2$ - answer $8$
- Step2: Calculate the index of this power - answer $4$ ($2^4$) and $2^3$ ($8$)
- Step3: Logarithm must be between $3$ and $4$.
- Step4: Set low = $3$, high = $4$
- Step5: Keep bisecting the interval till $2^x = 11$, everytime is $2^x > 11$ reset high or if $2^x<11$ reset low.

Where do you think this will overflow?

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing is essentially a "binary search" based on the Intermediate Value Theorem.  You are looking for the solution to the equation  $\log_2 11 - x = 0$, or what is equivalent, $2^x - 11 = 0$.  Since exponential and logarithmic functions are continuous for all real numbers, it is safe to apply this Theorem.  You know that $2^3 - 11 < 0$  and  $2^4 - 11 > 0$ , so the Theorem tells us that there must be a value of $x$ between 3 and 4  .

So your approach of dividing the interval in half each time and discarding the interval for which the sign of $2^x - 11$ *does not* change is reasonable.  You would continue this procedure until you reach the level of precision (number of decimal places) that you desire.  The method is pretty efficient:  you will gain another decimal place every two to three cycles.  (In five or six passes, I already reached an estimate of $\log_2 11 \approx 3.46$ to two decimal places. The calculator value is 3.459431619...)

Comment: @Pheonix When solving the equation $f(x)=0$, if $f$ is *nice enough*, then you can use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to find the root. This is much more efficient than a binary search.

Comment: @Daryl I am trying to find the log and not the root. Why do I need to find the root ? Can you illustrate with an example of 11 in this case ?

Comment: The root of the equation $2^x - 11 = 0$ _is_ $\log_2 11$.  You would set up $x_{n+1} = x_n - (\frac{2^{x_n}-11}{(\ln 2) \cdot 2^{x_n}})$.  You might use $x_0 = 4$ as your first guess, which gives  $x_1 = 4 - (\frac{2^4-11}{(\ln 2) \cdot 2^4})  \approx 4 - (\frac{5}{11.090}) \approx 3.549$.  You then replace $x_0 = 4$ with $x_1 = 3.549$ and repeat the calculation to obtain $x_2$.  It is a good idea when using root-estimators to use at least two more decimal places than the ultimate level of precision you desire; otherwise, you risk limiting the "resolution" for finding your next estimate.

Comment: I didn't propose Newton's method (or some other root-estimator scheme), since you were asking about binary searches.  Since computers are so fast now, either process would reach a high degree of precision in a tiny amount of time.  The binary search requires less computation per cycle and so advances quickly; Newton's Method takes more calculations at each level, but "homes in" on the result in fewer stages (when it _does_ settle down -- it has known limitations, which is why other root-estimators have been developed, though those require even more computation per cycle).

Comment: However, for a case that has $\log _2(x)$ as $x\to 0$, then speed is of the essence. It's the same case for large $x$. This is especially true for a binary search, as the boundaries further separate as $x$ increases.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to add an answer in response to my comments above. There is an efficient algorithm, which is described [here](http://www.claysturner.com/dsp/BinaryLogarithm.pdf). I will outline the algorithm below in MATLAB format.

```
function y = mylog (x,tol)
    % calculate log(x) in base 2 to tolerance tol

    y = 0; % initialise output
    b = 0.5; % initialise mantissa

    % arrange the input into a known range
    while x < 1
        x = x*2;
        y = y - 1;
        % move one bit to the left
    end
    while x >= 2
        x = x/2;
        y = y + 1;
        % move one bit to the right
    end
    % x is now in the range 1<=x<2

    % loop until desired tolerance met
    while b > tol
        x = x*x;

        % update the index
        if x >= 2
            x = x/2;
            y = y + b;
        end

        % scale for the next bit
        b = b/2;
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the representation in binary. You can just find the position of the most significant 1 for the integer part.

Then for the fractionary part, if close to 0, just use $b/2^{|\log_2 b|}-1$, if on the other hand close to 1, you can use $1-(b/2^{|\log_2 b|}-1) = 2 - b/2^{|\log_2 b|}$.

The first one is because of linearization of log(x+1) close to 0 is x and you can view the second one as a new rescaled linearization closer to the upper bound. However, in between these approximations become quite bad.

Here is a technique to "get rid of" a msb in the mantissa:

we use the fact that: $\log_2(1.5(x+1)) = \log_2(3)-1 + \log_2(x+1)$

---

Example:

Number to take binary logarithm of: $(50)_{10} = (110010)_2$

We approximate it as: $(5 + (log_2(3)-1) +2/32)$ which is 5.6474...
According to wolfram alpha the exact solution is 5.6438...

Here we need to store one number $log_2(3)-1$ so actually it requires a one element table. ;)